# How to create a confirm box?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a confirm box before insert any information on my database 
I want to get a confirm message on clicking Add. If the user selects 'Ok' then Add is done, else if 'Cancel' is clicked nothing happens. 
this is my html5 code

```js
<script>
    var option = "êtes-vous sûr de vouloir ajouter ce RDV?";
      $('#btnAdd').on('click', function(e){
      confirmDialog(option, function(){
       //My code to Add
      });
     });

        function confirmDialog(message, onConfirm){
         var fClose = function(){
       modal.modal("hide");
         };
         var modal = $("#confirmModal");
         modal.modal("show");
         $("#confirmMessage").empty().append(message);
         $("#confirmOk").one('click', onConfirm);
         $("#confirmOk").one('click', fClose);
         $("#confirmCancel").one("click", fClose);
        }
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Add RDV</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Modal dialog -->
 <div id="frmTest" tabindex="-1">
     <!-- CUTTED --><div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" id="insert-form">
        <label>Nom</label>
        <input type="text"id="name" class="form-control" required/>
        <label>Prenom</label>
        <input type="text"id="lname" class="form-control" required/>
        <label>Date</label>
        <input type="text"id="date" class="form-control" required/>
        <label>Heure</label>
        <input type="text"id="heure" class="form-control" required/>
        
        </form>
      </div>
        <div id="step1" class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase btn btn-default" id="btnAdd"> Add</button>
  </div>
 </div>

    <!-- Modal confirm -->
 <div class="modal" id="confirmModal" style="display: none; z-index: 1050;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header"style="background-color:green;color:white;text-align:center">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" >Confirmation!</h4>
         </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="confirmMessage">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="confirmOk">Ok</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirmCancel">Cancel</button>
          </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

my php code is in the same page with my html and javascript code how shall i pricise to javascript which code need to execute

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding the event listeners:

```
$("#confirmOk").one('click', onConfirm);
```

It should be:

```
$("#confirmOk").on('click', onConfirm);
```

Also, `onConfirm` function is undefined.

Comment: alistaircol thank you !! my confirm box is ready my problem now is how to integrate my php code on javascrip?

Comment: @Jennifer95 you need ajax

Comment: Try doing some research, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ @Jennifer95